# Problema de validación login

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código para validar un usuario y una contraseña recogida de un formulario. El paso de datos entre páginas funciona correctamente y la conexión con la BD también está bien. El problema es que al comprobar el usuario y la contraseña el IF siempre me mete en el caso de "el usuario no existe". ¿Podríais indicarme qué está mal en el código por favor? Muchas gracias.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "database";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$subs_usuario = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);
$subs_pass = utf8_decode($_POST['password']);

$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario= '$subs_usuario' AND password= '$subs_pass'");

if($sql==""){
    echo "usuario no existe";
}
else{
    print "Bienvenido";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me he fijado en la variable $sql te falta poner otro parámetro donde tienes que poner la conexión a la base de datos, debería de funcionarte, espero ayudar, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
$subs_usuario = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);
$subs_pass = utf8_decode($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$subs_usuario' AND email='$subs_pass'";

$consulta = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(!$consulta){

    echo "usuario no existe";

} else {

    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
    var_dump($resultado);

    echo "Bienvenido ";
}

mysqli_free_result($consulta);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

En la variable $consulta en la función mysqli_query te faltó poner la variable $conn, para que se pudiera conectar a tu base de datos, la variable $resultado esta guardando un array asociativo de los resultados obtenidos en la consulta y los muestra con var_dump, var_dump te muestra todo el array con el tipo de dato que tiene cada campo, el método mysqli_free_result libera el conjunto de resultados obtenidos en la consulta. Espero haberlo explicado bien.

Comment: Genial Jonasdamher. Millones de gracias. Una última pregunta si me permites por favor. Con "var_dump($resultado)" he conseguido extraer un array con todos los datos. Ahora en función de los datos de una columna de la BD, necesito redireccionar a un sitio u a otro la salida. Se que eso se hace con un header, pero mi duda surge en como utilizar la función "mysqli_fetch_assoc" para separar todo el conjunto de columnas que yo tengo y quedarme solo con una y compararla. No se si me explico. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Solucionado. He podido resolverlo con mysqli_fetch_object. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perdón, no estaba atento, me alegro que lo solucionaras.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que te fata pasar el argumento `$conn` en la función `mysqli_query`

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario= '$subs_usuario' AND password= '$subs_pass'");
```

Saludos.